# Diagonalizable Matrices Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

**Question:** Suppose $A$ is a square diagonalizable matrix with this property

$\exists k\in \mathbb Z_{>0}, A^k = 0$

I am to prove that $A$ must be the zero matrix.

I tried using property that $A^kx=\lambda^kx$ and $A^k=PB^kP^{-1}$ separately but couldn't come to any logical conclusion. Looking for advice on how to go about this.

Comment: if$B$ is a diagonal matrix and there is some $k$ with $B^k = 0,$ what does that tell you about $B \; ? \; \;$

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then we can write $A=PDP^{-1}$.

Also, $A^k=PD^kP^{-1}$

If $A^k=0$, then $D^k=0$. Note that $D=diag(d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_k)$ is a diagonal matrix.

If $d_i^k=0$, try to deduce the value of $d_i$ and should be able to complete the proof.

Comment: bingo, $A=PDP^{-1}=P0P^{-1}=0$.